# Error Code: 1064 - MY SQL : DYNAMIC ROWS TO COLUMN

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

```sql
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(case when subject_details.subject_Name = ''',
      subject_details.subject_Name,
      ''' then (marks.internal_Marks+marks.external_Marks) End) AS ',
      REPLACE(subject_details.subject_Name, ' ', '')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM subject_details;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT stud.student_Name,',@sql , 'FROM marks
INNER JOIN student_details AS stud ON stud.pkey = marks.fk_Student_Name
INNER JOIN subject_details ON subject_details.pkey = marks.fk_Subject_Name
INNER JOIN dept_name ON dept_name.pkey = subject_details.fk_Dept_Name
GROUP BY stud.student_Name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

When i run the code I get this error:

> Error Code: 1064
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM marks
> INNER JOIN student_details AS stud ON stud.pkey = marks.fk_Student_Na' at line 1

Comment: Although I don't know MySQL at all, looks like to me that you don't have commas defined in your dynamic column definition, and also you don't have a leading space prior to the `FROM` (so the final alias would be concatenated to the keyword `FROM`).

Comment: Before `PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;`, why not run `print @sql` and see what the code is preforming?